# Disable or greyout rows in CListCtrl Customdraw function

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl, custom-draw

I have a CListCtrl in a MFC dialog. What I have to do is disbling some the items based on a condition so that user can't select that.Till now I have changed the colour but thats not proper a solution. My code looks like this:

```
void CSomeDialog::OnCustomdrawElementList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{

NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pLVCD = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>( pNMHDR );
*pResult = 0;

if ( CDDS_PREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage )
    {
    *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    }
else if ( CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage )
    {

    COLORREF crText;

    //Here I want to do disable based on some condition of the data related to the item//
    if ( (pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec % 2) == 0 )
        crText = RGB(255,0,0);
    else if ( (pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec % 2) == 1 )
        crText = RGB(0,255,0);

    // Storing the color back 
    pLVCD->clrText = crText;

    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
    }
}
```

I am unable to find any reference on how to disable a row yet.

Another problem , even after managing the disbling part how to get the data related to the item here in this custom draw function? can pLVCD->nmcd.lItemlParam be used to call GetItemData(). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing and disabling a row is something different.

To disable a row, so that it can not be selected, use [LVN_ITEMCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Check ifthe status is changing from unselected to selected (compare uNewState and uOldState about a change to LVIS_SELECTED). If you don't want to allow a selection of this item, just return TRUE to the WM_NOTIFY message.

About to associate data to an item in a list view it is easy to use the free [lParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) field. Here you can store some user data, that may point to an internal structure that you have. You can also access this field in drawing routines.

Comment: Actually I have to somehow let the user instantly know that some items are not valid for present context. For that I have to grey out the row.I can change the colours but that is not going to stop them from selecting invalids.  Alternatives like disabling the OK button / internally handling the invalid selection / warning popup is not preferred.